# Go Template Lifecycle

Tags: go, templates, webpack, go-templates

In my Go template I have a function called "asset":

```
<html>
  {{ asset "application.css" }}
</html>
```

This function opens a webpack manifest.json and finds the corresponding hashed file:

```
func asset(s string) string {
  data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("manifest.json")
  // do stuff with data
  return filename
}
```

My question is regarding the implications on performance. When is this function being called? Is go opening the manifest file every time the template is executed; every time a user visits the page? Or is it called on the initial `template.New("").ParseFiles()` call?

Would I be better off opening the file on application startup, and storing a map of filenames in a global variable? That makes more sense to me, but what would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registered `asset()` function is called every time the template is executed, and thus the file `"manifest.json"` is opened and read every time.

If its content doesn't change, load it just once, either on first use, or better, on application startup, which may be during package initialization (in a package `init()` function).

If you do this, you can pass the `filename` to the template execution, so it won't even require registering a custom function.